# How to generate a psv file from apache drill

Tags: apache-drill

The current way I am going about creating a pipe seperated value (psv) file is to first create a view with a query like

Create view ABC as 
select column 1 || '|' || column 2 || '|' || ..

And then use the !record to do a select * from ABC.

This is causing a lot of development time and error prone as the files that I need to generate have 100's of columns.

Is there a simple way of going about this?

Comment: you could have used CTAS command if you need to generate csv file. Check [docs](http://drill.apache.org/docs/create-table-as-ctas-command/)

Comment: I need a psv file. Drill does have a csv generator option. But I am looking for a way to generate psv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Storage plugin create custom format.
Here is the documentation
https://drill.apache.org/docs/plugin-configuration-basics/

```
"formats": {
"psv": {
  "type": "text",
  "extensions": [
    "tbl"
  ],
  "delimiter": "|"
 }
}
```

Alter you session to set your default store

```
alter session set `store.format`='psv';
```

Use CTAS to write the data in above specified format

```
create table `users.vgunnu`.`vt_del_test` as select * from dfs.root.`/tmp/test_parquet` limit 3;
```

More info for the format
http://drill.apache.org/docs/create-table-as-ctas-command/

Comment: Are you sure **alter session set `store.format`='psv';** this works? Have you tried it? As per my understading csv, json and parquet can be input for this.

Comment: I do not have admin access to edit the plugin. I am trying to see if an admin can create it for me.